# Shredding files in trash

Tags: command-line

When downloading files/photos from some sites, you don't always get what you thought you were going to get. Sometimes, you can get things that are downright illegal. I have deleted them but the residue and some of the files are still in the trash bin. How do I shred everything in the trash bin? I want everything gone, the risks are too great. Also, are there other areas that should be checked?

Comment: Maybe you don't have rights to delete some files. Try with root then. Your trash bin is located in /home/username/.local/share/Trash/files If possible only delete the content in the files directory and NOT the "files" folder itself and the "info" folder.